# WiFi enabled device recognize WiFi access points?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

How does WiFi enabled device recognize WiFi access points in programming language?

Answer (score 2):

from: http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks

```
package com.android.wifitester;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WifiTester extends Activity {
    TextView mainText;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
       mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
       registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       mainWifi.startScan();
       mainText.setText("\\nStarting Scan...\\n");
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\\n");
            }
            mainText.setText(sb);
        }
    }
}
```